# How can I share variable values between different classes?

Tags: c#, variables, methods

I'm pretty new to C# so I've begun building a simple RPG game as a means of implementing my skills in a fun way as I learn. One particular thing that I'm having an issue with is finding a way to share variable values such as the player name and current health throughout multiple classes. For example:

```
// below is the program class where the variables are given new values:

    class Program
    {
        public static Player thePlayer = new Player();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");
            thePlayer.name = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Your name is " + thePlayer.name + ".");
            Console.WriteLine("Your health: " + thePlayer.health + "");

            Console.ReadLine();

            thePlayer.health--;
            Console.WriteLine("You get stung by a bee and lose 1 health.");
            Console.WriteLine("Your health is now " + thePlayer.health + ".");

            Console.ReadLine();

            Locations.Location2();
        }
    }

// below is the class that represents the initial values of the two variables:

    public class Player
    {
        public string name;
        public int health = 10;
    }

// the class below represents another in-game location the player can access. Currently, the player name and health value modified in the program class doesn't carry over to the Locations class as the locations class has its own values for the two variables.

    public class Locations
    {
        public static Player thePlayer = new Player();
        public static void Location2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You're in location 2 now.");
            Console.WriteLine("Your name is " + thePlayer.name + ".");
            Console.WriteLine("Your health: " + thePlayer.health +"");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

My question is how do I make it so that in Location 2, the current player name and health represent the same values that they were previously in the program class?

Comment: in your `Program` class, you've set `thePlayer` as `public static`, and without setting an access modifier on the `Program` class it defaults to `internal` which should be accessible from `Locations`. So in `Locations` if you remove your `thePayer` field and replace references to it with `Program.thePlayer`. It will likely work as you require. Not a great pattern to follow, but as you're learning this will get you moving forward.

Comment: I'n general, when one object knows something and a second object (created by the first object) wants to know something, the first object tells the second. In your example, the class Prgram crates the player ad the location; if location wants to know player, program has to give it. Program hence does `Locations.ThePlayer = this.ThePlayer`. In c# we name public things in PascalCase LikeThis, notCamelCaseLikeThis. Ultimately, static will hinder your learning so you should bear in mind the notion of starting to avoid it soon

Comment: Thank you for the responses, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instance in `Program` is public and static, so you can access it anywhere. (As it is, you're creating a `new` one just for `Locations`.)

```
public class Locations
{
    //No additional variable needed here, you already have one in Program

    public static void Location2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You're in location 2 now.");

        //Change these
        Console.WriteLine("Your name is " + Program.thePlayer.name + ".");
        Console.WriteLine("Your health: " + Program.thePlayer.health +"");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is probably the best way of getting the result I want for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the player as a parameter to `Location2`, for example:

```
public class Locations
{
    public static void Location2(Player thePlayer)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You're in location 2 now.");
        Console.WriteLine("Your name is " + thePlayer.name + ".");
        Console.WriteLine("Your health: " + thePlayer.health +"");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Or if you're confident that there will only ever be one player, then you can modify the `Locations` class to use non-static methods, and use a constructor:

```
public class Locations
{
    private Player thePlayer;

    public Locations(Player player)
    {
        thePlayer = player;
    }
    
    public void Location2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You're in location 2 now.");
        Console.WriteLine("Your name is " + thePlayer.name + ".");
        Console.WriteLine("Your health: " + thePlayer.health +"");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
Locations location = new Locations(thePlayer);
location.Location2();
```

Comment: One player only, yeah. So what would my program class need to look like in this case, if you don't mind me asking? Thank you for your comment by the way, I appreciate the help!

Comment: Just replace `Locations.Locations2()` with the code in the **Usage** section